# Defining boundaries and communicating between aggregate roots

Tags: domain-driven-design, aggregateroot

I could use some help understanding my domain model a bit and making sure I am approaching the design correctly.

I have an aggregate root called Department.  The Department object has several child value types that help define the business notion of a 'department.' In my UI users can list, create, edit and delete Department objects.

I have another aggregate root called Project.  A Project has several child value types but also has a relationship to a Department in that each Project is 'owned' by a department.  Projects can be created, edited, deleted, etc. and doing so has no impact on the department whereas removing a Department also removes any projects it owns.

My UI will display a list of Projects based on the departments the current user is authorized to access.  They may be able to access more than one department.  When displayed as both a list item as well as in detail, I need to show the Department logo with the Project.

My first thought was the Project was an aggregate root with a simple DepartmentID property that could be used to 'lookup' the Department.  But now I'm starting to think that I really only have one aggregate root: Department.

What do you think?

**UPDATE**

I don't know if it is key to the discussion or changes anything but the following thought occurred to me after reading the first couple of answers.

Department appears to have two contexts:

1. As a stand-alone entity that
   supports modification.
2. As a child of a Project in which
   case is contains read-only data and
   no behavior.

This makes me think that I should have two 'objects' in my model, an aggregate root for case #1 and a value type for case #2.  Am I on the right track?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the Project can't exist without a Department it's probably not an Aggregate Root. From your description it sounds like you only have one AR - the Department, which you use to manage  the projects inside it.

If your behavior is mostly CRUD, i would not recommend building a full blown domain model for it since there are probably simpler approaches you can take.

**UPDATE**
As you mention, you might have 2 bounded contexts here. One where the Department is an AR and the Projects are entities of this AR. In this context you would perform operations on your Departments. In a second BC your Project could be the AR and the Departments could be entities or VOs. This would allow you to work directly with projects.

I would also recommend going over this with your domain expert and see if these concepts fit well in your UL, or maybe search for some missing concept that can clarify your model. I would especially look for a concept that might link projects to departments.

Comment: Only the interface/API for Departments is CRUD. There are a LOT of operations and behaviors associated with a Project which is why I was originally considering it an aggregate.

Comment: Even though a Project cannot 'exist' without ownership from a Department, couldn't this also be considered a validation rule? What I mean is, if Project isn't an aggregate root, then I have to instantiate the Department in order to navigate to the Project when many of my use-cases start with browsing a list of Projects, selecting an item and performing a task against that item, such as editing it's properties. Do I really need to go through Department to do this or, in this case, is Department just a value type decorating Project? This is the source of my confusion.

Comment: If you model them as separate ARs and then delete a Department, if you want to also delete the Projects you will have to use a unit of work which spans across ARs which is not recommended and in some cases might not even be possible ( partitioning, events sourcing ). I'll update the answer to provide info related to the updated section.

Comment: Would your thoughts change if 'deleting' a Department simply set a flag and did not physically remove the record from the data store?

Comment: Not really. You stil need to update the flag in the same transaction.

Answer (score 1):

I think it's perfectly defensible to have both Project and Department be aggregate roots, since they are both managed independently.

That is, every Project and every Department have some kind of unique identifier, and while you can add Projects to Departments, Projects themselves are probably complicated enough (with their own lifecycles, their own child objects etc.) to warrant aggregate root status.

You just have to keep a reference to the Department in each Project.

Comment: Do you mean "reference to the Department in each Project" literally in that when I return a Project object it contains a reference to the associated Department object (and all of its children)? Of would it be better to have Project exposes a DepartmentID property and lookup the Department object by some other means when needed?

Comment: Well, in your Domain you may keep an actual reference, or just a Guid (or other uniquely-identifying) property.

It depends on whether you always need access to every Project whenever you're acting on your Department, which I think is unlikely.

How you model the Domain is really up to you, as long as you manage the relationships properly. So far I prefer to work with IDs. Let's say your Project aggregate root has a DepartmentId property. Then in case your business logic needs it, you just retrieve the right Department from the DepartmentRepository by calling its GetById method.

Comment: A lot of people like just having a reference to the Id.  I use Nhibernate.  Nhibernate has lazy loading, so in actuality I just have the id until i try to access the other aggregate, then NH goes and gets it.  This abstracts retrieving the other ag.  In reference to your statement " a reference to the associated Department object (and all of its children)"  I think that if you are going to maintain a reference to the actual object then you MUST use some form of lazy loading. Otherwise in very short order you would retrieve one object and end up with a your entire system object graph in memory.

Answer (score 0):

Few simple questions to be answered:

1) can the department domain object live by its own without the Project domain object. - If yes, then the department is an aggregate.

2) Is the Project domain object can live by its own - If yes, then the Project is also an aggregate

3) Is Project has relationship with one Department - Then it should be part of the Project aggregate exposed as property Department

4) Is Department has relation ship with one or more Project objects - The the Project aggregate should be part of the Department aggregate object.

So, Using Department aggregate object you might need to access the list of Project(s) object and once you have the Project object you might need to access the Department object. It is a circular reference which is obsoletely fine.

It is a typical example of Employee has a manager and manager has a list of employees

Comment: Yes to all 4 questions. How would you handle the relationships? Would the Department property of Project reference the actual Department object or a light-weight value object representing the department in the context of the Project?